# How to cast blocks to and from void *

Tags: objective-c, casting, objective-c-blocks, void-pointers

So, I'm trying to pass a block as an `NSAlert` `contextInfo` parameter.

```
[myAlert beginSheetModalForWindow: theWindow
                    modalDelegate: myAlert
                   didEndSelector: @selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                      contextInfo: (void *) aBlock];
```

and get it back on the other end:

```
void (^responseBlock)() = (__bridge_transfer void (^)()) contextInfo;
```

Which works, to an extent. Before my call to `beginSheetModalForWindow:...` aBlock is at `0x00007fff610e1ec0`, and in the response (`alertDidEnd:...`), contextInfo is at `0x00007fff610e1ec0`.

However, when I try to call the block:

```
responseBlock();
```

I get the following error

> error: called object type '__block_literal_generic *' is not a function or function pointer
> error: 1 errors parsing expression

How does one properly cast blocks to an from `void *`s for the sake of simple transference?

**Edit:**
Full attempted code, using the cast methods suggested in the answers. I now receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the `responseBlock();` call.

```
- (void)alertDidEnd:(NSAlert *)alert returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    void (^responseBlock)() = (__bridge typeof(responseBlock)) contextInfo;

    switch (returnCode)
    {
        case NSCancelButton:
        {
            break;
        }
        
        case NSOKButton:
        {
            responseBlock();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Other Notes:**
When using `__bridge`, the memory address of `responseBlock` and `contextInfo` are different, whereas with `__bridge_transfer`, they are the same. Neither alleviates the EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue.

## WORKING:

```
[myAlert beginSheetModalForWindow: theWindow
                    modalDelegate: myAlert
                   didEndSelector: @selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                      contextInfo: (__bridge_retained void *) [aBlock copy]];
```

and later...

```
void (^responseBlock)() = (__bridge_transfer typeof(responseBlock)) contextInfo;
```

Comment: I have an answer, but I cannot reproduce your problem. I wonder why that is... do you have any extra warning/compile flags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a small example. I think that the problem with your code is that you are trying to use `__bridge_transfer` with a `void *` which isn't memory managed with ARC:

```
void takesBlock(void *asPointer)
{
    void (^asBlock)() = (__bridge typeof asBlock) asPointer;

    asBlock();
}

int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        takesBlock((__bridge void *)[^{
            NSLog(@"Hello World!");
        } copy]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void (^responseBlock)() = (__bridge typeof responseBlock) contextInfo;` gives me the syntax error: `Expected ')'` on `responseBlock` in `typeof responseBlock`. Thoughts?

Comment: @pcperini can you post the contents of the function into a paste bin?

Comment: Added the full function to the question. Error has changed from a type error to a full blown EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @pcperini did you remember to copy the block from the stack?

Comment: No, I hadn't. I fiddle with it some more and got an answer. Thanks!