# How to define the block with universal signature

Tags: ios, objective-c

Get confused a bit with a question of how to pass the block to the method but without the defined (concrete) params.

like that:

```
 - (void)someMethodWithBlockAsParam:(generic block)block
```

is it possible at all regarding to Obj-C

Seems like I saw this trick somewhere but can't remember where.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Could you pass pointer-to-void and cast? See. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106224/how-to-cast-blocks-to-and-from-void

Comment: @matt - surely casting a pointer to an object, the block, to a void pointer is not the best choice in an ARC world...

Comment: @CRD I don't see what it has to do with ARC. The answer to question I linked to shows you how to handle the memory management. Pointer-to-void _is_ the generic type in C/Objective-C; there are lots of situations where we pass an object pointer cast as pointer-to-void.

Comment: @matt - surely `id` is the generic *object* type in Objective-C, and if that type is used in conjunction with ARC there is no need to handle the memory management in a situation like this - it is handled automatically. Now I'm at a Mac I've added an answer showing this. Why `bridge` when you don't need to? Or maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @CRD I like your idea, actually; this was a good discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare *something*, otherwise the callsite for that block won't know what to pass in or what to expect in return.  In particular, it needs to know whether they are going to be Objective C objects or not, because otherwise it can't refcount them correctly.

If you just want a block that takes no arguments and returns nothing (a callback, basically) then you can use `dispatch_block_t`:

```
- (void)someMethodWithBlockAsParam:(dispatch_block_t)block
```

Comment: Perhaps he wants to be able to pass a generic block, and on the receiving end cast it to a specific signature before actually calling it (Like you would do with variables and `void*`). Not sure if that's possible, though.

Comment: Umm, if you want a block like that, you use `dispatch_block_t`.  That's what it's there for.

Answer (score 2):

> Get confused a bit with a question of how to pass the block to the method but without the defined (concrete) params.

It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking here, but it sounds like you wish to be able to pass *any* block to a method which presumably at some later point you cast to a specific block type so you can call it. If so:

A block in modern (post late 2014 - see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152580/cocoa-blocks-as-strong-pointers-vs-copy) for why that date) ARC Objective-C is a fully automatically managed object. Therefore the standard "any object" type `id` may be used to pass any block.

For example given:

```
// a specific block type
typedef id (^SelectBlock)(NSArray *, NSUInteger);

// method which takes a general object and casts to a specific block type
- (void) useBlock:(id)blockObj
{
   SelectBlock sb = (SelectBlock)blockObj;
   id item = sb(@[@"apple", @"pear", @"plum"], 2);
   NSLog(@"Result: %@", item);
```

}

```
// method which pass a block as "any object"
- (void) test:(NSUInteger)offset
{
   SelectBlock mySelect = ^(NSArray *collection, NSUInteger index)
                          {
                             return collection[index-offset];
                          };
   [self useBlock:(id)mySelect];
}
```

then the call:

```
[self test:1];
```

will result in `pear` being output.

Passing a block "generically" in this way is only useful if the original type is somehow known so the `id` typed valued can be cast back to the correct block type to invoke the block.

Comment: Good answer. Of course, if the passed block does not conform to the signature it is cast to, calling it will trigger a runtime error, right?

Comment: @NicolasMiari - absolutely! This is the standard problem when you cast away type information and is not specific to blocks, if you cast back to the wrong type bad things can happen. Hence the comment in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

How about you define a block with one `NSDictionary` parameter where you can place any number and any kinds of objects as the parameters?

```
typedef void (^aBlock)(NSDictionary* parameters);
```